# Python 3.6 connection to Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, driver, python-3.6

I am fairly new to Python and currently using version 3.6. I need to connect to an oracle 11g database. I have tried:

- using pyodbc with driver *Oracle in OraClient12Home1*. That did not work and gave the error  *[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error\n (12560) (SQLDriverConnect)')*
- installing cx_oracle, but that is not compatible to Python 3.6

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

u can choose cx_Oracle 6.0rc2

[cx_Oracle-6.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/43/ec/a84f69c28b22e41e62657331e164fb07749682ca4abc1f4f2e981b8b475b/cx_Oracle-6.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=68151bf2b3839e0eedfaa2a328f4edb1)

[cx_Oracle-6.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/81/4f/0ea5cb6a745ff469fab1b939860afc174c07310e00c025fde8842598f3c6/cx_Oracle-6.0rc2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=f5edb52718e66ee2db55793aafdafab3)